# is there a way to link one of the field in ACF field group, to a field in a media attachment page?

Tags: plugins, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

so i created a post type that will allow user to enter Basic Information such as patient id and full name. and since they're allowed to upload pictures in the media page, i would like the user to be able to differentiate which picture belongs to which patient by entering their id in the field provided. i want this field to be linked to the one in the Basic Information page. for instance if the entered id does not exist, a warning like "The id does not exist" will be displayed.

Basic Information page kinda looks like:
[image: Basic Information Page]

i want the patient's ID field to be linked over here
[image: Patient's ID field]

so is this possible?

Comment: Probably, but this is an ACF question requiring ACF specific knowledge and expertise, you should ask it in an ACF community/ACF support/ACF meetup/ACF FB group/etc, this stack is for general WP development and 3rd party plugin dev support is offtopic